# Splitting Detox E2E Tests in React Native for Separate Screens

Tags: react-native, expo, detox

I'm working on a React Native project with Detox for end-to-end testing. My current setup involves a test that starts on an activation screen and, after certain interactions, navigates to a login screen. This entire flow is in one test file, but for better maintainability, I want to split it into two separate tests in different files.

Here's an excerpt from my current test file:

```
import { device, element, by, waitFor } from 'detox';
import TEST_CREDENTIALS from './utils/testCredentials';

// As a rule of thumb, end every test with an expect line

// Define constants
const TEST_IDS = {
  haveAccountBtn: 'HaveAccountBtn',
  activationCodeInput: 'ActivationCodeInput',
  loginScreenWelcomeText: 'LoginScreenWelcomeText',
  activationNextButton: 'ActivationNextButton',
  logoImg: 'logo-img',
  activationView: 'ActivationView',
  playerAppLoginEmailInput: 'PlayerAppLoginEmailInput',
  playerAppLoginPasswordInput: 'PlayerAppLoginPasswordInput',
  playerAppLoginButton: 'PlayerAppLoginButton',
  notificationModal: 'NotificationModal',
  notificationModalAllowButton: 'NotificationModalAllowButton',
  notificationModalSkipForNowButton: 'NotificationModalSkipForNowButton'

  // ... other test IDs
};
const TIMEOUTS = {
  short: 2000,
  long: 6000
  // ... other timeout values
};

describe('player app Activation screen', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    //new instance makes to close the app and start it again

    await device.launchApp({ newInstance: true });
    // await device.launchApp();

    await device.openURL({
      url: `exp+next11-reaxt-native-v2://expo-development-client/?url=${encodeURIComponent(
        `http://localhost:8081`
      )}`
    });
  });
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should display and tap the "Got It" button in the development console ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.text('Got It')))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.long);

    await element(by.text('Got It')).tap();
  });

  it('should swipe down the development console', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.text('Connected to:')))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.long);

    await element(by.text('Connected to:')).swipe('down');
  });

  it('should display the "Welcome" title', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.text('Welcome!')))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);
    await expect(element(by.text('Welcome!'))).toBeVisible();
  });

  it('should have a disabled button', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.activationNextButton)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);
  });

  it('should show the activation code input field', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.activationCodeInput)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.long);

    // Tap on the input field
    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.activationCodeInput)).tap();

    // // Type text into the input field
    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.activationCodeInput)).typeText('123456');

    // // Clear the text
    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.activationCodeInput)).clearText();
  });

  it('should display and tap the "Already have an account" button', async () => {
    // Assertion

    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.haveAccountBtn)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);

    // await expect(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.haveAccountBtn))).toBeVisible();

    // Action
    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.haveAccountBtn)).tap();

    // Assertion

    await expect(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.loginScreenWelcomeText))).toBeVisible();

    await expect(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.haveAccountBtn))).not.toBeVisible();
  });

  //FOR THE LOGIN SCREEN

  //TODO: need to somehow put the login tests in a login test file

  it('should display a "Email" input on the login page ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginEmailInput)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginEmailInput)).tap();

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginEmailInput)).typeText(
      TEST_CREDENTIALS.email
    );
  });

  it('should display a "Password" input on the login page ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginPasswordInput)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginPasswordInput)).tap();

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginPasswordInput)).typeText(
      TEST_CREDENTIALS.password
    );
  });

  it('should display "Login" button on the login page ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginButton))).toBeVisible();

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginButton)).tap();
  });

  //NOTIFICATION MODAL

  //TODO: da gi podelam vo dav it  bloka i da dodam not visible after closing the modal

  it('should display "NotificationModal" ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.notificationModal)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(60000);
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.notificationModalSkipForNowButton)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(60000);

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.notificationModalSkipForNowButton)).tap();
  });
});
```

I tried some things but they where not working i made another test file but i dont know what it needs to be there so the test continues from the before test

```
  it('should display a "Email" input on the login page ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginEmailInput)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginEmailInput)).tap();

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginEmailInput)).typeText(
      TEST_CREDENTIALS.email
    );
  });

  it('should display a "Password" input on the login page ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginPasswordInput)))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(TIMEOUTS.short);

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginPasswordInput)).tap();

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginPasswordInput)).typeText(
      TEST_CREDENTIALS.password
    );
  });

  it('should display "Login" button on the login page ', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginButton))).toBeVisible();

    await element(by.id(TEST_IDS.playerAppLoginButton)).tap();
  });
```

i need this two it blocks to be in a differnet test file